# Angular 2 - Implementation of shared services

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-services

I'm trying to implement a solution I found right here in Stack Overflow, but facing difficulty. I've a service and a component and something is not correct on the implementation.

The error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'next' of undefined
What could be wrong or missing ? Is there something more missing ?
Also on my terminal window, I got this error, but it's not reflect on my browser console: error TS1005: '=>' expected.

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Observer} from 'rxjs/Observer';
@Injectable()
export class GlobalService {
data: any;
dataChange: Observable<any>;
constructor() {
this.dataChange = new Observable((observer:Observer) { // this is the TS1005 error.
  this.dataChangeObserver = observer;
});
}
setData(data:any) {
this.data = data;
this.dataChangeObserver.next(this.data); //Line of the critical error (next)
} 
}
```

and this is the component that's consume the service....(I will place only the relevant lines)

```
import {GlobalService} from "../../../global.service";
import(...)
@Component({
    providers: [GlobalService],
template: `<p>{{myData}}<>/p><span (click)="addTag(1, 'test')">Add more</span>` 
});
export class MyComponent  {
    addTag (id,desc){
       this._global.setData({ attr: 'some value' });
    }
}
constructor(private _global: GlobalService) {

}
```

So, what's wrong and/or missing to make this simple component display results and add new elements and be observable ? I never implemented observables before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is not so clear and so becomes hard to understand. Still tried to help you this way. Check and let me know if it doesn't work.

```
...
import {Injectable,EventEmitter,Output} from 'angular2/core';
@Injectable()
export class GlobalService {
data: any;    
@Output dataChangeObserver: EventEmitter=new EventEmitter();

  constructor() {
  });

  setData(data:any) {
    this.data = data;
    this.dataChangeObserver.emit(this.data); 
    return this.dataChangeObserver;
  } 
}
```

---

```
export class MyComponent  {
    constructor(private _global: GlobalService) {

     }

    addTag (id,desc){
       this._global.setData({ attr: 'some value' })
                 .subscribe((res)=>{this.myData=res},
                 err=>console.log(err),   //removed dot
                 ()=>console.log('recived data') //removed dot                    
                  );
     }
}
```

Comment: Hi @micronyks ! can you confirm this ? dataChangeObserver: EventEmitter=new EventEmitter(); (Generic type 'EventEmitter<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).______ and this._global.setData({ attr: 'some value' })
                 .subscribe((res)=>{this.myData=res},
                 .err=>console.log(err),
                 .()=>console.log('recived data')
                 ); -----> Property 'myData' does not exist and Argument expression expected on the dots that's connects err and ()

Comment: Oh may be `. (dot)` could be the problem. wait a min. I'm updating answer.

Comment: LOL...let me try to be more human...the line you wrote "new EventEmitter();" gave me an error: Generic type 'EventEmitter<T>' requires 1 type argument(s)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106268/discussion-between-micronyks-and-marco-s-junior).

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: Will this work when you create a new component and creating new instance of GlobalService in the constructor, will the data still be there?