# How can I declare a global variable in Angular 2 and up / Typescript?

Tags: typescript, angular

I would like some variables to be accessible everywhere in an `Angular 2` in the `Typescript` language. How should I go about accomplishing this?

Comment: If they're static variables there's no need to use services. Just add a variable in some file and then import it everywhere you need it.

Comment: Unfortunately Angular2 having exception at runtime, saying `Uncaught ReferenceError: Settings is not defined`. The class `Settings` with public static variables is set to export and have imported where it used.

Comment: I know this post is old and that there is many valid answers. But like Eric mentioned. If its a simple value that you want to declare and have access to through out your application you can create a class and export the class with a static property. Static variables are associated with a class rather than an instance of the class. You can import the class and will be able to access the property from the class.directly.

Answer (score 225, accepted):

Here is the simplest solution without `Service` or `Observer`:

Put the global variables in a file and export them.

```
//
// ===== File globals.ts    
//
'use strict';

export const sep='/';
export const version: string="22.2.2";
```

To use globals in another file, use an `import` statement:
`import * as myGlobals from 'globals';`

Example:

```
// 
// ===== File heroes.component.ts    
//
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router} from 'angular2/router';
import {HeroService} from './hero.service';
import {HeroDetailComponent} from './hero-detail.component';
import {Hero} from './hero';
import * as myGlobals from 'globals'; //<==== this one (**Updated**)
 
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {
    public heroes: Hero[];
    public selectedHero: Hero;
    // 
    //
    // Here we access the global var reference.
    //  
    public helloString: string="hello " + myGlobals.sep + " there";

         ...

        }
    }
```

Comment: Got an error on the import statement.  had to use `import * as globs from 'globals'`

Comment: Why did you use "require" instead of import from ?

Comment: I would use `export const` instead of `export var` - you really want to make sure those global variables cannot be changed

Comment: I prefer this way but it aint working......for the current cli version this is what the error i get **Module build failed: Error: /home/pratik/Desktop/My Projects/ng2projects/ng2-app-build/src/app/home/addnewuser/add.user.component.ts (6,23): 'from' expected.)**

Comment: Importing like this is not valid in TypeScript anymore. Please update your answer. Correct would be: `import * as myGlobals from 'globals'`

Comment: It's not recognizing as a file, I'm getting cannot find module 'globals', any idea guys?

Comment: `import * as myGlobals from './path/to/globals';`

Comment: does this work with instance variables?

Comment: I too got error on import statement. so used `import * as myGlobals from '../globals';` which solves problem as my global.ts is at root folder

Comment: `const` and `static` mean read-only across all sessions/logins, what about session ID?

Answer (score 98):

I like the solution from @supercobra too. 
I just would like to improve it slightly. If you export an object which contains all the constants, you could simply use es6 **import** the module without using **require**.

I also used Object.freeze to make the properties become true constants. If you are interested in the topic, you could read this [post](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es6-const).

```
// global.ts

 export const GlobalVariable = Object.freeze({
     BASE_API_URL: 'http://example.com/',
     //... more of your variables
 });
```

Refer the module using import.

```
//anotherfile.ts that refers to global constants
import { GlobalVariable } from './path/global';

export class HeroService {
    private baseApiUrl = GlobalVariable.BASE_API_URL;

    //... more code
}
```

Comment: this to me is the best solution because (1) it's the simplest with least amount of code and (2) it doesn't require you to Inject some darn service into every single component or place you want to use it in, nor does it require you to register it in @NgModule. I can't for the life of me figure out why it would be necessary to create an Angular 2 Service to do this, but perhaps there's something I'm overlooking? I'm using this great solution for now but please do let me know why the other more complicated answers here are better?

Comment: Your GlobalVariable is not a variable. Its a constant.

Comment: @PriyaR LOL, yes, you are right. I assumed the main objective of the question was to have a safe way to access some values globally, so I improvised. Otherwise, feel free to change const to var, you get your variable.

Comment: The down side of Object.freeze is that values are not typed. Anyway, wrapping values in a class is a better design from my perspective. So we have to choose between typed properties and true constants.

Comment: how to set GlobalVariable.BASE_API_URL in another component..?

Comment: If you want to set the value in different components, I think using service might be better if the components are unrelated. Otherwise, you should assign the constant value to a variable in the parent component. 

See if this post helps, https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/

Comment: you do not need to wrap and freeze with an object. Indeed, declaring as const is sufficient. Plus, for modules accessing the variable, these cannot modify the variable as it does not belong to it. External modules have to use a function given by the same module which modifies internally the variable. It's also one of the purpose on why it's better to use modules.

Answer (score 68):

A shared service is the best approach

```
export class SharedService {
  globalVar:string;
}
```

But you need to be very careful when registering it to be able to share a single instance for whole your application. You need to define it when registering your application:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [SharedService]);
```

But not to define it again within the `providers` attributes of your components:

```
@Component({
  (...)
  providers: [ SharedService ], // No
  (...)
})
```

Otherwise a new instance of your service will be created for the component and its sub-components.

You can have a look at this question regarding how dependency injection and hierarchical injectors work in Angular 2:

- [What's the best way to inject one service into another in angular 2 (Beta)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804298/whats-the-best-way-to-inject-one-service-into-another-in-angular-2-beta/34807397)

You should notice that you can also define `Observable` properties in the service to notify parts of your application when your global properties change:

```
export class SharedService {
  globalVar:string;
  globalVarUpdate:Observable<string>;
  globalVarObserver:Observer;

  constructor() {
    this.globalVarUpdate = Observable.create((observer:Observer) => {
      this.globalVarObserver = observer;
    });
  }

  updateGlobalVar(newValue:string) {
    this.globalVar = newValue;
    this.globalVarObserver.next(this.globalVar);
  }
}
```

See this question for more details:

- [Delegation: EventEmitter or Observable in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376854/delegation-eventemitter-or-observable-in-angular2/35568924)

Comment: Seems this one is different though. Seems @Rat2000 thinks our answer is wrong. I usually leave this decision to others than peaple providing competing answers but if he is convinced our answers are wrong then I think it's valid. The docs he linked to in a comment to my answer mention that it's DISCOURAGED but I see no disadvantage and the arguments in the docs are quite weak. It's also quite common to add providers to bootstrap. What would be the purpose of this argument anyway. And what about `HTTP_PROVIDERS` and similar, should they also not be added to `bootstrap()`?

Comment: Yes I just read the argument and the section in the doc. Honnestly I don't really understand why it's discouraged from the doc. Is it a way to define a logical split: what is Angular2 core specific (routing providers, http providers) when bootstrapping and what is application-specific in the application component injector. That said we can only have one sub injector (the application one) for the root one (defined when bootstrapping). Does I miss something? Moreover in the doc regarding hierarchical injectors, service providers are defined within the root injector ;-)

Comment: The only argument I see is that keeping the scope as narrow as possible and using the root component is at least in theory slightly narrower than using `bootstrap()` but in practice it doesn't matter. I think listing them in `boostrap()` makes the code easier to understand. A component has providers, directives, a template. I find this overloaded without global providers listed there as well. Therefore I prefer `bootstrap()`.

Comment: and how does one reference such global variables? even after bootstrapping the service, calling `alert(globalVar)` results in an error.

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but you will want something like: 
alert(this.SharedService.globalVar)

Answer (score 41):

See for example [Angular 2 - Implementation of shared services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35993778/angular-2-implementation-of-shared-services)

```ts
@Injectable() 
export class MyGlobals {
  readonly myConfigValue:string = 'abc';
}

@NgModule({
  providers: [MyGlobals],
  ...
})

class MyComponent {
  constructor(private myGlobals:MyGlobals) {
    console.log(myGlobals.myConfigValue);
  }
}
```

or provide individual values

```ts
@NgModule({
  providers: [{provide: 'myConfigValue', useValue: 'abc'}],
  ...
})

class MyComponent {
  constructor(@Inject('myConfigValue') private myConfigValue:string) {
    console.log(myConfigValue);
  }
}
```

Comment: Since Angular2 beta 7(I think) you should not register your service directly in the root component(aka bootstrap). You can however inject there a specific provider if you want to override something in your application.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Of course you can register a service in `bootstrap()`. `bootstrap()` and root component are two different things. When you call `bootstrap(AppComponent, [MyService])` you register the service in `boostrap()` and `AppComponent` is the root component. The docs mention somewhere that it's prefered to register providers (service) in the root components `providers: ['MyService']` but I haven't found any argument in favor or against `bootstrap()` or root component yet.

Comment: You can find your argument in the angular 2guide section  Dependency Injection( https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html ). Like they say, you can do it but it is DISCOURAGED. This user is asking for the best way to iinject something witch clearly your solution is not corect. same goes for @ThierryTemplier

Comment: Is this the argument "The preferred approach is to register application providers in application components. Because the HeroService is used within the Heroes feature area — and nowhere else — the ideal place to register it is in the top-level HeroesComponent.
" or is there more?

Comment: I will up vote in 20 minutes when I can vote again. I was wrong, my apologies. They do behave differently.( https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection.html ) Apparently your solution is what the op needed.

Comment: No worries, we are all here to learn. Sure, they behave differently but not much. Adding providers to `bootstrap()` and the root component have quite the similar effect, they are shared with the whole application. There are of course subtle differences.

Comment: I think the more important quote from the Angular doc is "The bootstrap provider option is intended for configuring and overriding Angular's own preregistered services, such as its routing support."  I rarely put services in bootstrap myself, and I'm glad to see the docs now suggest that.

Comment: don't forget to export the class

Answer (score 20):

Create Globals class in **app/globals.ts**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

Injectable()
export class Globals{
    VAR1 = 'value1';
    VAR2 = 'value2';
}
```

In your component:

```
import { Globals } from './globals';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    providers: [ Globals ],
    template: `<h1>My Component {{globals.VAR1}}<h1/>`
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private globals: Globals){
    }
}
```

**Note**: You can add Globals service provider directly to the module instead of the component, and you will not need to add as a provider to every component in that module.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [...],
    declarations: [...],
    providers: [ Globals ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer, as it offers a more portable approach than having to add the service to each component across the app. Thank you!

Comment: The code is working. But note that injecting class `Globals` with also adding it to `providers: [ ... ]` means you cannot change a value inside one component and then ask for the updated value inside a second component. Every time you inject `Globals` it is a fresh instance. If you want to change this behaviour, simply do **NOT** add `Globals`  as provider.

Comment: just a note, it should be `@Injectable()`

Answer (score 13):

IMHO for Angular2 (v2.2.3) the best way is to add services that contain the global variable and inject them into components without the `providers` tag inside the `@Component` annotation. By this way you are able to share information between components.

A sample service that **owns** a global variable:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'

@Injectable()
export class SomeSharedService {
  public globalVar = '';
}
```

A sample component that **updates** the value of your global variable:

```
import { SomeSharedService } from '../services/index';

@Component({
  templateUrl: '...'
})
export class UpdatingComponent {

  constructor(private someSharedService: SomeSharedService) { }

  updateValue() {
    this.someSharedService.globalVar = 'updated value';
  }
}
```

A sample component that **reads** the value of your global variable:

```
import { SomeSharedService } from '../services/index';

@Component({
  templateUrl: '...'
})
export class ReadingComponent {

  constructor(private someSharedService: SomeSharedService) { }

  readValue() {
    let valueReadOut = this.someSharedService.globalVar;
    // do something with the value read out
  }
}
```

> Note that `providers: [ SomeSharedService ]` should **not** be added to your `@Component` annotation. By not adding this line injection will always give you the same instance of `SomeSharedService`. If you add the line a freshly created instance is injected.

Comment: But without adding the line of providers, I got an error like this: `Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for SomeSharedService`

Comment: I see. I should add `providers: [SomeSharedService]` in the parent module file. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't work when we are lazy loading modules.

Answer (score 12):

I don't know the best way, but the easiest way if you want to define a global variable inside of a component is to use `window` variable to write like this:

`window.GlobalVariable = "what ever!"`

you don't need to pass it to bootstrap or import it other places, and it is globally accessibly to all JS (not only angular 2 components).

Comment: I'd say it's the worst way. Using a static variable isn't more complicated but isn't that ugly either ;-)

Comment: I agree it makes difficult to manage. However I ended to use them in development till I find what I want to put in productions. In static variable you have to import them again and again everywhere you want to use, beside there was a case I was producing my view on the go with jquery in angular components - there was no template, and to add events to produced DOM using static variable is pain.

Comment: Plus, it is not static, you can change the value from everywhere!

Comment: It also wrecks server side rendering. Stay away from directly manipulating the window or document.

Comment: It is only 1 line, it does not follow Angular guidelines

Comment: Agreed. but I personally don't follow any guideline in my life (if I could do better than that).

Answer (score 9):

That's the way I use it:

global.ts

```
export var server: string = 'http://localhost:4200/';
export var var2: number = 2;
export var var3: string = 'var3';
```

to use it just import like that:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import * as glob from '../shared/global'; //<== HERE

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    private AuhtorizationServer = glob.server
}
```

EDITED:
Droped "_" prefixed as recommended.

Comment: Do not use "_" as a prefix for private properties.https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Coding-guidelines

Answer (score 4):

I think the best way is to share an object with global variables throughout your application by exporting and importing it where you want.

First create a new **.ts** file for example **globals.ts** and declare an object. I gave it an **Object** type but you also could use an [any type or {}](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28795689/1783311)

```
export let globalVariables: Object = {
 version: '1.3.3.7',
 author: '0x1ad2',
 everything: 42
};
```

After that import it

```
import {globalVariables} from "path/to/your/globals.ts"
```

And use it

```
console.log(globalVariables);
```

Answer (score 3):

I like the answer of @supercobra, but I would use the const keyword as it is in ES6 already available:

```
//
// ===== File globals.ts    
//
'use strict';

export const sep='/';
export const version: string="22.2.2";
```