# Angular2/Ionic2 where to define global variables?

Tags: angular, global-variables, ionic2

I am having tough time defining a global variable to be accessible in the whole app.
The app is based on Ionic2 and Angular2.

I tried to many approaches but none worked. In some examples on SO I can't understand where to store the js file physically.

Exampe I tried: [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36158848/what-is-the-best-way-to-declare-a-global-variable-in-angular-2-typescript)

Comment: The example you have given is how you would define a "global" variable in typescript. What are you struggling with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create Globals class in app/globals.ts:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

Injectable()
export class Globals{
    VAR1 = 'value1';
    VAR2 = 'value2';
}
```

In your component:

```js
import { Globals } from './globals';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    providers: [ Globals ],
    template: `<h1>My Component {{globals.VAR1}}<h1/>`
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private globals: Globals){
    }
}
```

You can use your globals in the html with `{{globals.VARIABLENAME}}`

Do not add class Globals as provider

Comment: Note that this way it is possible to get multiple instances of the Globals class. Would be better to only declare the "Globals" once in app.module.ts providers