# Angular - access value from a service in root module

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dependency-injection, angular-services

I'm working on internationalisation of an Angular app where I need to dynamically detect the locale that the user has *actively* selected for the app (the user must actively switch locale for the site to be displayed in their preferred language).

In my root module I specify the following provider for `TRANSLATIONS`, where the required xlf file (the translations file) is determined dynamically using a factory that depends on the value of my `LOCALE_ID`:

### app.module.ts

```
... imports go here

export function selectedLocaleFactory(): string {
  return LocaleService.getCurrentLanguage();
}

providers:
[
  LocaleService,
  {
    provide: TRANSLATIONS,
    useFactory: (locale) => {
      locale = locale || 'en'; // default to english if no locale provided
      return require(`raw-loader!../locale/messages.${locale}.xlf`);
    },
    deps: [LOCALE_ID]
  },
  {
    provide: LOCALE_ID,
    useFactory: selectedLocaleFactory
  }
]
```

As you can see, in the `TRANSLATIONS` provider, I'm determining the translation file to use based on the value of `LOCALE_ID`.

`LOCALE_ID` is determined by using another factory (`selectedLocaleFactory`), which simply tries to return a LOCALE_ID value using a method `getCurrentLanguage` from the `LocalService`. I'm not sure this is the correct/best way to get a value from my service - I mean `selectedLocaleFactory` isn't really acting as a true 'factory', and services are designed to be injected.

In any case, I get this compile error in `app.module.ts`:

`Property 'getCurrentLanguage' does not exist on type 'typeof LocaleService'.`

Here's an extract from my `LocalService`:

```
@Injectable()
export class LocaleService {

  private currLanguage: string;

  constructor( private router: Router ) {
         // this.currLanguage is set here - based on the URL being accessed by the user
  }

  getCurrentLanguage() { 
    return this.currLanguage;
  }
```

If I make getCurrentLanguage a static method inside the `LocaleService` it's still inaccessible:

```
  static getCurrentLanguage() { 
    return this.currLanguage;
  }
```

**UPDATE:**

I realised that I need to instantiate the service to access the appropriate method:

```
export function selectedLocaleFactory(): string {
  var localeService = new LocaleService(null);
  return localeService.getCurrentLanguage();
}
```

My `LocaleService` has a `Router` dependency, so I just set this to null. It still feels though like I'm trying to do this the wrong way. My `LocaleService` should really be a singleton and I'm concerned I may end up with issues using my current approach (for example issues with shadowing). Is there a more 'correct' I can access a property from my service inside my root module?

The answer by @Thierry Templier here - [What is the best way to declare a global variable in Angular 2 / Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36158848/what-is-the-best-way-to-declare-a-global-variable-in-angular-2-typescript) suggests bootstrapping the service to get access to one of its variables, however this approach gives me an error saying I can't use the service as an entry point.