# Declaring a global variable in Angular 6 / Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have two files, `'Drawer.ts'` and the `'sidenav-open-close.component.ts'` componenet.

I need a variable to be shared between these two, with the option to change it's value in `'Drawer.ts'`, and `'sidenav-open-close.component.ts'` will act accordingly.

I tried using this method - 
[What is the best way to declare a global variable in Angular 2 / Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36158848/what-is-the-best-way-to-declare-a-global-variable-in-angular-2-typescript/36183988)
and created a file named globals.ts with these conntent:

```
'use strict';
export var diffMode : boolean = false;
```

and imported it in both files with `import * as myGlobals from './src/globals.ts';`

I managed to read diffMode, but when trying to set it through `'Drawer.ts'` i get the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property diffMode of [object Object] which has 
only a getter
```

Help will be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: W̶h̶y̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶e̶ ̶s̶t̶o̶r̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶a̶ ̶s̶h̶a̶r̶e̶d̶ ̶s̶e̶r̶v̶i̶c̶e̶,̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶a̶c̶c̶e̶s̶s̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶r̶e̶?̶ .Thanks @T.J.Crowder!

Comment: Will you only be changing the value inside Drawer.ts? and is sidenav-open-close.component.ts a child, sibling, or parent of Drawer.ts?

Comment: @KhaledShaaban - I believe that's what he/she is trying to do by following [the question he/she linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36158848/what-is-the-best-way-to-declare-a-global-variable-in-angular-2-typescript/36183988).

Comment: I'm trying to avoid `Service` for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With JavaScript modules (aka "ESM" for ECMAScript Module), which TypeScript now uses, imports are a *read-only view* of the export, which is why you can't write to `diffMode` from outside the module it's defined in.

If you need to write to it from a different module, you can expose a function to set its value instead:

```
'use strict';
export var diffMode : boolean = false;
export function setDiffMode(flag: boolean) {
    diffMode = flag;
}
```

...and then call that function from the other module, rather than writing to it directly.

[Live Example](https://embed.plnkr.co/LS08xobV0AgdypUoOc6o/) (in JavaScript, but it doesn't matter) on plunker (Stack Snippets don't allow modules, sadly).

`main.js`:

```
const handle = setInterval(() => {
    const p = document.createElement("p");
    p.appendChild(
        document.createTextNode(`diffMode = ${diffMode}`)
    );
    document.body.appendChild(p);
}, 250);
setTimeout(() => {
    clearInterval(handle);
}, 1000);

export var diffMode = false;
export function setDiffMode(flag) {
    diffMode = flag;
}
```

`othermod.js`:

```
import {diffMode, setDiffMode} from "./main.js";

setTimeout(() => {
    setDiffMode(true);
}, 500);
```

If you run that, you'll see that the change `othermod.js` makes to `diffMode` does happen and get observed by `main.js`'s code.

---

Side note: Modules are always in strict mode, so you don't need the `'use strict';` at the top.